# Flowchart on Beamer Size

Tags: tikz-pgf, beamer

I have a flowchart in an `article` document.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usepackage{float}
\usetikzlibrary{matrix,shapes,arrows,positioning,chains}

\begin{document}
    \tikzstyle{block} = [draw, rectangle, text centered,text width=7.5cm, minimum height=8mm,node distance=10em]
    \tikzstyle{line} = [draw, -latex']
    \tikzstyle(cloud)=[ellipse,draw,  text centered,node distance=10em,minimum height=2em,minimum size=0cm]
    \tikzstyle{decision}=[draw,diamond,text centered, node distance=10em,inner sep=2pt,minimum size=0cm]
    \tikzstyle{io}=[trapezium,minimum size=0cm,trapezium left angle=70,trapezium right angle=-70,minimum height=4em, draw, text width=4.5em, text centered, node distance=10em, inner sep=2pt]

\begin{figure}[H]
    \centering
    \begin{tikzpicture}
        \node[draw,ellipse](Mulai){Mulai};
        \node[block,below of=Mulai,node distance=1.5cm](step1){Studi literatur};
        \node[block,below of=step1,node distance=2cm](step2){Formulasi model matematika};
        \node[block,below of=step2,node distance=2cm](step3){Analisis kestabilan titik ekulibrium};
        \node[block,below of=step3,node distance=2cm](step4){Penyelesaian kontrol optimal menggunakan \textit{Pontryagin Maximum Principle}};
        \node[block,below of=step4,node distance=2.5cm](step5){Simulasi numerik dengan program \textit{MATLAB}};
        \node[io,below of=step5,node distance=2.5cm](Penutup){Kesimpulan dan Saran};
        \node[draw,ellipse,below of=Penutup,node distance=2cm](End){Selesai};

        \path[line](Mulai)--(step1);
        \path[line](step1)--(step2);
        \path[line](step2)--(step3);
        \path[line](step3)--(step4);
        \path[line](step4)--(step5);
        \path[line](step5)--(Penutup);    
        \path[line](Penutup)--(End);

    \end{tikzpicture}
    \caption{\textit{Flowchart} Alur Penelitian}
\end{figure}
\end{document}
```

How to fit it into a `beamer` document?

Answer (score 3):

Maybe a `matrix of nodes` as an alternative ?

It's easy to fine tune the vertical space and the style to apply to nodes in the definition of the matrix style.

```
\documentclass[9pt]{beamer}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usetikzlibrary{matrix,shapes,arrows,positioning,chains}

\begin{document}
\begin{frame}
    \begin{figure}
        \begin{tikzpicture}
            \tikzset{
                block/.style={
                    draw, 
                    rectangle,
                    align=flush center,
                    text width=7.5cm, 
                    minimum height=1.2em,
                },
                line/.style={
                    draw, 
                    -latex',
                },
                io/.style={
                    trapezium,
                    minimum size=0cm,
                    trapezium left angle=70,
                    trapezium right angle=-70,
                    minimum height=3em, 
                    draw, 
                    text width=4.5em, 
                    text centered,
                    inner sep=2pt,
                },
            }
            
            \matrix (m) [
                matrix of nodes, 
                row sep = 3mm,
                row 1/.style={nodes={draw,ellipse}}, 
                row 2/.style={nodes={block}}, 
                row 3/.style={nodes={block}}, 
                row 4/.style={nodes={block}}, 
                row 5/.style={nodes={block}}, 
                row 6/.style={nodes={block}}, 
                row 7/.style={nodes={io}}, 
                row 8/.style={nodes={draw,ellipse}}, 
            ]{
                Mulai \\
                Studi literatur \\
                Formulasi model matematika \\
                Analisis kestabilan titik ekulibrium \\
                Penyelesaian kontrol optimal menggunakan \emph{Pontryagin Maximum Principle} \\
                Simulasi numerik dengan program \emph{MATLAB} \\
                Kesimpulan dan Saran \\
                Selesai \\
            };

            \draw[line] (m-1-1) -- (m-2-1);  
            \draw[line] (m-2-1) -- (m-3-1);  
            \draw[line] (m-3-1) -- (m-4-1);  
            \draw[line] (m-4-1) -- (m-5-1);  
            \draw[line] (m-5-1) -- (m-6-1);  
            \draw[line] (m-6-1) -- (m-7-1);  
            \draw[line] (m-7-1) -- (m-8-1);  

        \end{tikzpicture}
        \caption{\textit{Flowchart} Alur Penelitian}
    \end{figure}
\end{frame}
\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: Okay, thank you. It works.

Answer (score 3):

Exploiting `chains` library code become simple and very short:

```
\documentclass{beamer}
%\setbeamertemplate{caption}[numbered]
\setbeamerfont{caption}{size=\footnotesize}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usetikzlibrary{arrows.meta,
                chains,
                positioning,
                shapes}
\tikzset{FlowChart/.style = {% can be used in any flowchart
       arr/.style = {semithick, -{Stealth[scale=0.8]}},
      base/.style = {draw, text width=62mm, minimum height=6mm, align=flush center},
 startstop/.style = {ellipse, draw, inner xsep = 0pt},
   process/.style = {base},
        io/.style = {base, trapezium, trapezium stretches body,
                     trapezium left angle=70, trapezium right angle=110,
                     text width=31mm},
  decision/.style = {base, diamond, aspect=1.5, inner sep=0pt},
   every edge quotes/.style = {auto=right}
                            }
        }

\begin{document}
\begin{frame}
\frametitle{Frame title}
    \begin{figure}
    \footnotesize
    \begin{tikzpicture}[FlowChart,
node distance = 3mm,
  start chain = going below
                        ]
    \begin{scope}[nodes={on chain, join=by arr}]
\node   [startstop] {Mulai};
\node   [process]   {Studi literatur};
\node   [process]   {Formulasi model matematika};
\node   [process]   {Analisis kestabilan titik ekulibrium};
\node   [process]   {Penyelesaian kontrol optimal menggunakan
                     \emph{Pontryagin Maximum Principle}};
\node   [process]   {Simulasi numerik dengan program \emph{MATLAB}};
\node   [io]        {Kesimpulan dan Saran};
\node   [startstop] {Selesai};
    \end{scope}
    \end{tikzpicture}
\caption{\textit{Flowchart} Alur Penelitian}
    \end{figure}
\end{frame}
\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: I was waiting for your answer on chains +1

Comment: @JeT,thank you very much! Also +1 for matrix ;-)

Answer (score 2):

I assume that you're asking about how to do the two things:

1. how to create a horizontal flow diagram
2. how to fit it to a beamer slide

For the first point, you can replace `below of` by `right of`. For the second point, you can either fiddle around manually with sizes or simply scale the whole tikzpicture using `\begin{tikzpicture}[scale=0.65,...]`.

This is a quick try on your example:

```
\documentclass[aspectratio=169]{beamer} 
\usepackage{tikz}
\usepackage{float}
\usetikzlibrary{matrix,shapes,arrows,positioning,chains}


\begin{document}
 \tikzstyle{block} = [draw, rectangle, text centered,text width=1.7cm, minimum height=0.6\textheight,node distance=4em]
    \tikzstyle{line} = [draw, -latex']
    \tikzstyle(cloud)=[ellipse,draw,  text centered,node distance=10em,minimum height=2em,minimum size=0cm]
    \tikzstyle{decision}=[draw,diamond,text centered, node distance=10em,inner sep=2pt,minimum size=0cm]
    \tikzstyle{io}=[trapezium,minimum size=0cm,trapezium left angle=70,trapezium right angle=-70,minimum height=5em, draw, text width=3.5em, text centered, node distance=5em, inner sep=2pt]
    
    \begin{frame}[t, fragile]
        \begin{figure}[H]
            \centering  % horizontal centering
            \vfill      % vertical centering
            \begin{tikzpicture}[scale=0.65, every node/.style={scale=0.65}]
                \node[draw,ellipse, minimum width=7em, minimum height=4em](Mulai){Mulai};
                \node[block,right of=Mulai, anchor=west, node distance=5em](step1){Studi literatur};
                \node[block,right of=step1, anchor=west](step2){Formulasi model matematika};
                \node[block,right of=step2, anchor=west](step3){Analisis kestabilan titik ekulibrium};
                \node[block,right of=step3, anchor=west](step4){Penyelesaian kontrol optimal menggunakan \textit{Pontryagin Maximum Principle}};
                \node[block,right of=step4, anchor=west](step5){Simulasi numerik dengan program \textit{MATLAB}};
                \node[io,right of=step5, anchor=west](Penutup){Kesimpulan dan Saran};
                \node[draw,ellipse,right of=Penutup,anchor=west, node distance=5em, minimum width=7em, minimum height=4em](End){Selesai};
                
                \path[line](Mulai)--(step1);
                \path[line](step1)--(step2);
                \path[line](step2)--(step3);
                \path[line](step3)--(step4);
                \path[line](step4)--(step5);
                \path[line](step5)--(Penutup);    
                \path[line](Penutup)--(End);
                
            \end{tikzpicture}
            \caption{\textit{Flowchart} Alur Penelitian}
        \end{figure}
        \vfill  
    \end{frame}

\end{document}
```

This results in the following beamer slide:
[image]

Answer (score 2):

Here is a solution:

```
\documentclass[9pt]{beamer}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usetikzlibrary{matrix,shapes,arrows,positioning,chains}

\begin{document}
\begin{frame}
\begin{figure}
  \begin{tikzpicture}
    \tikzset{
      block/.style={draw, rectangle,align=flush center,text width=7.5cm, minimum height=1.2em},
      line/.style={draw, -latex'},
      io/.style={
        trapezium,minimum size=0cm,trapezium left angle=70,trapezium right angle=-70,minimum height=3em, draw, text width=4.5em, text centered,inner sep=2pt},
    }
    
    \node[draw,ellipse](Mulai){Mulai};
    \node[block,below=2mm of Mulai](step1){Studi literatur};
    \node[block,below=3mm of step1](step2){Formulasi model matematika};
    \node[block,below=3mm of step2](step3){Analisis kestabilan titik ekulibrium};
    \node[block,below=3mm of step3](step4){Penyelesaian kontrol optimal menggunakan \emph{Pontryagin Maximum Principle}};
    \node[block,below=3mm of step4](step5){Simulasi numerik dengan program \emph{MATLAB}};
    \node[io,below=4mm of step5](Penutup){Kesimpulan dan Saran};
    \node[draw,ellipse,below=4mm of Penutup](End){Selesai};
    
    \path[line](Mulai)--(step1);
    \path[line](step1)--(step2);
    \path[line](step2)--(step3);
    \path[line](step3)--(step4);
    \path[line](step4)--(step5);
    \path[line](step5)--(Penutup);    
    \path[line](Penutup)--(End);
  \end{tikzpicture}
  \caption{\textit{Flowchart} Alur Penelitian}
\end{figure}
\end{frame}
\end{document}
```

[image]